# List Overridable Methods in Visual Studio Code (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, overriding, intellisense

I recently switched to Visual Studio Code and there's one feature so far that I have been dearly missing and that is the ability to autocomplete overridable methods.

In the full Visual Studio versions you were able to type `override` and the IDE would list all the methods of the current class that were marked abstract or virtual in any of the parent classes. This feature seems to be missing from Visual Studio Code. Is there a setting that could be tweaked or does anybody know about an extension that would add this kinda feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have type the first character of the override method.It just doesn't trigger on SPACE.

Comment: You could also press ctrl+space to open intellisense after you press the space, however, that solution and this answer both have the same problem, and that is, it will not auto complete the return type of the method. You still have to know what the return type is and manually type it out.

Comment: @Nick I'm using TypeScript, and pressing ctrl+space bring up "no suggestions" for public or protected methods from the base class.